# Rails Action Mailer works locally but not in Production: Heroku: Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

I'm working on a project (Rails backend, React frontend) where I would like the user to receive an email when they register an account.  I set up action-mailer with Gmail locally and it works fine Then when I deploy my backend to Heroku, it doesn't send the email or return a response to the frontend.  Here it my development.rb file

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'

Rails.application.configure do
  
  config.cache_classes = false

  # Do not eager load code on boot.
  config.eager_load = false

  # Show full error reports.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = true

  # Enable/disable caching. By default caching is disabled.
  # Run rails dev:cache to toggle caching.
  if Rails.root.join('tmp', 'caching-dev.txt').exist?
    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    config.public_file_server.headers = {
      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.to_i}"
    }
  else
    config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

    config.cache_store = :null_store
  end

  # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :log

  # Raise exceptions for disallowed deprecations.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :raise

  # Tell Active Support which deprecation messages to disallow.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  config.active_record.migration_error = :page_load

  config.active_record.verbose_query_logs = true

  config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    domain: 'example.com',
    user_name: ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
    password: ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

And my production.rb file looks like this :

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/integer/time'

Rails.application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb.

  # Code is not reloaded between requests.
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Eager load code on boot. This eager loads most of Rails and
  # your application in memory, allowing both threaded web servers
  # and those relying on copy on write to perform better.
  # Rake tasks automatically ignore this option for performance.
  config.eager_load = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on.
  config.consider_all_requests_local = false

  # Ensures that a master key has been made available in either ENV["RAILS_MASTER_KEY"]
  # or in config/master.key. This key is used to decrypt credentials (and other encrypted files).
  config.require_master_key = true

  # Disable serving static files from the `/public` folder by default since
  # Apache or NGINX already handles this.
  config.public_file_server.enabled = ENV['RAILS_SERVE_STATIC_FILES'].present?

  config.log_level = :info

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags.
  config.log_tags = [:request_id]

  # Use a different cache store in production.
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Use a real queuing backend for Active Job (and separate queues per environment).
  # config.active_job.queue_adapter     = :resque
  # config.active_job.queue_name_prefix = "Art_Wall_production"

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation cannot be found).
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners.
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log disallowed deprecations.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation = :log

  # Tell Active Support which deprecation messages to disallow.
  config.active_support.disallowed_deprecation_warnings = []

  # Use default logging formatter so that PID and timestamp are not suppressed.
  config.log_formatter = ::Logger::Formatter.new

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups.
  # require "syslog/logger"
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Syslog::Logger.new 'app-name')
  if ENV['RAILS_LOG_TO_STDOUT'].present?
    logger           = ActiveSupport::Logger.new(STDOUT)
    logger.formatter = config.log_formatter
    config.logger    = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(logger)
  end

  # Do not dump schema after migrations.
  config.active_record.dump_schema_after_migration = false

  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'art-wall-api.herokuapp.com', protocol: 'https' }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 587,
    user_name: ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'],
    password: ENV['GMAIL_PASSWORD'],
    authentication: 'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }
end
```

This is where i'm calling the method "notify_user":

```
# post to db
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      NewUserEmailMailer.notify_user(@user).deliver # call to mailer controller
      @token = encode({ id: @user.id })
      render json: {
        user: @user.attributes.except('password_digest'),
        token: @token
      }, status: :created
    else
      # puts @user.errors.full_messages
      render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

and here is the controller

```
class NewUserEmailMailer < ApplicationMailer
  def notify_user(user)
    @user = user
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to Art Wall')
  end
end
```

Again,  it works fine during development but when I deploy, it saves the user info in heroku db but then never sends the email OR returns a response to the frontend.  Any help would be appreciated! Thanks

Comment: Anything in the production log?

Comment: This is the last 4 lines of "heroku logs --tail:  2021-09-01T17:48:21.657593+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2021-09-01T17:48:21.657461 #4] FATAL -- : [13788b95-c2f2-4c69-9377-8ca7b56b4889]
2021-09-01T17:48:21.657595+00:00 app[web.1]: [13788b95-c2f2-4c69-9377-8ca7b56b4889] ArgumentError (SMTP From address may not be blank: nil):
2021-09-01T17:48:21.657596+00:00 app[web.1]: [13788b95-c2f2-4c69-9377-8ca7b56b4889]

Comment: 2021-09-01T17:48:21.657597+00:00 app[web.1]: [13788b95-c2f2-4c69-9377-8ca7b56b4889] app/controllers/users_controller.rb:20:in `create'
2021-09-01T17:48:21.665404+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/users" host=art-wall-api.herokuapp.com request_id=13788b95-c2f2-4c69-9377-8ca7b56b4889 fwd="98.11.107.123" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=686ms status=500 bytes=374 protocol=https

Comment: Sorry I'm new at this.  Is this what you meant?  It is saying SMTP From address may not be blank, but I'm pretty sure I put the address in correctly

Comment: I don't see a from address in the code you shared - i'd try adding it to the `mail(` call and see if that resolves the issue, then you can figure out why it's not coming through.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that.  I'm also entering(sending) and receiving from the same email to test.  I guess I shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: So I updated my mail() call :   mail(to: @user.email, from: ENV['GMAIL_USERNAME'], subject: 'Welcome to Art Wall').

Comment: GMAIL_USERNAME is env variable with my email.  still shows 500 internal server error